# Coreml: Model class has not been generated yet

Tags: ios, xcode, coreml

I've converted model from keras with coremltools, added it to project and added to targets. And then when i'm pressing on model in navigator in Model Class section i'm getting "Model class has not been generated yet.". What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: I am receiving this same behavior as well. Using CompCars Dataset model.

Comment: That model name 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cited from apple dev forum:

> Xcode has stopped automatically adding the coreml model to the build
>   settings of your project. To solve, go to your target, go to build
>   phases, find compile sources and add your coreml model. After this,
>   the model class is generated.

Answer (score 3):

It means you first need to build your project (Cmd+B). The model class is generated as part of the build process.

Comment: IDK why this was downvoted but in my case it was the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

`target` -> `Build Setting` -> `CoreML Model Compiler - Code Generation` -> `CoreML Generated Model Inherits NSObject` -> YES

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me even though I have added it in the `compile sources` section of build settings didn't worked.

After many hours, Cracked it by setting the "CoreML Code Generation Language" setting in project build settings to something else than `none` or to the specific language solved the issue.